# How to conclude this solution is periodic?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, mathematical-physics

I've met the following problem in finishing my argument. The expression I ended with is
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\xi}U(\xi)=\pm\sqrt{C_1-\frac{U^4(\xi)}{2}},$$ with $U:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and $C_1$ is non zero because otherwise I would have no square root unless $U\equiv 0$, which is not admissible in my situation. Therefore I would say the solution $U$ is periodic, and also I would like to find some bounds on the period.

The first problem I ask is the following: how would you proceed in showing that $U$ is periodic?

The second question is to find some bounds on the period. I mean: separating the variables and choosing the $+$ sign one gets $$\frac{\mathrm d U}{\sqrt{C_1-\frac{U^4}{2}}}=\mathrm d \xi,$$ but then I derived no useful informations about the period. Could you help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say "...to me periodicity is quite obvious from the expression", do you mean that *exclusively* from the expression you know this or because of this *and other* info that you did not display you know this? I ask because I see the expression and I've not the slightest idea how only from it it is obvious the function is periodic and even less what its period would be...

Comment: maybe you're right.. call it intuition..but I asked exactly because most of the times intuition is wrong..

Comment: I edited my post at any rate not to confuse or to make you believe I've got the solution.. which is not true...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simplicity I will denote $U$ by $x$. Suppose $x$ is a non-zero solution of your ODE. Then $x$ solves the Hamiltonian equation
$$\tag{HS}
\ddot{y}(t)+y^3(t)=0,
$$
and in particular
$$
\frac{1}{2}\dot{x}^2(t)+\frac{1}{4}x^4(t)=h
$$
for some constant $h>0$ not dependending on $t$.  Therefore
$$
(x,\dot{x})=(\pm h^{1/4}\sqrt{2\sin\theta},\sqrt{2h}\cos\theta),
$$
for some function $\theta:\mathbb{R} \to [2k\pi,(2k+1)\pi],\ k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $x$ solves (HS), it follows that $\theta$ solves the ODE
$$
\ddot{\theta}=4\sqrt{h}\cos\theta.
$$
The function
$$\tag{1}
t \mapsto \phi(t)=\theta(t/2h^{1/4})-\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
then solves the (mathematical) pendulum equation
$$\tag{P}
\ddot{\phi}=-\sin\phi.
$$
We recall that any solution $\phi$ of (P) has constant energy, i.e.
$$
E(t)=\frac{1}{2}\dot{\phi}^2(t)+1-\cos\phi(t)=E(0) \quad \forall t.
$$
It is well known that (P) admits **periodic, homoclinic, and heteroclinic solutions**.
Let $\phi_\tau$ be a periodic solution of (P) with period $\tau>0$. 
Then 
$$
x_\tau(t)=\pm h\sqrt{\cos\phi_\tau(2h^{1/4}t)}
$$ 
is a periodic solution of (HS) with period $T_h=\tau/2h^{1/4}$ and energy $h$.

Let $x^T$ be a periodic solution solution of (HS) with period $T=T_h>0$, and energy $h>0$. Setting 
$$
r=\sqrt{2}h^{1/4},
$$
we have
\begin{eqnarray}
T_h&=&2\sqrt{2}\int_{-r}^r\frac{dy}{\sqrt{4h-y^4}}=4\sqrt{2}\int_0^r\frac{dy}{\sqrt{4h-y^4}}\cr
&=&\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{r}\int_0^1\frac{ds}{\sqrt{1-s^4}}=4h^{-1/4}\int_0^1\frac{ds}{\sqrt{1-s^4}}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: ...and that last integral is in fact related to the so-called [lemniscatic constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LemniscateConstant.html).

Answer (score 3):

Since $U$ and $U'$ satisfy
$$
2\,U'^2+U^4=2C_1\tag{1}
$$
$U'$ is dependent on $U$ in such a way that $(U,U')$ follows the path below clockwise:

$\hspace{3.5cm}$[image]

If the solution is $C^2$, then $U$ won't stop at $U^4=2C_1$, and if $U$ can get to that point in a finite amount of time, it will follow this oval and be periodic.

Using the substitution $(2C_1)^{1/4}t^{1/4}=U$, we get the period to be
$$
\begin{align}
4\int_0^{\sqrt[4]{2C_1}}\frac{\mathrm d U}{\sqrt{C_1-\frac{U^4}{2}}}
&=(2/C_1)^{1/4}\int_0^1\frac{t^{-3/4}\,\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1-t}}\\
&=(2/C_1)^{1/4}\,\mathrm{B}(1/4,1/2)\\
&=(2\pi^2/C_1)^{1/4}\frac{\Gamma(1/4)}{\Gamma(3/4)}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
where
$$
\sqrt[4]{2}\,\mathrm{B}(1/4,1/2)=6.236338999021645\tag{3}
$$

Comment: To produce rob's plot: `ParametricPlot[{JacobiCN[u, 1/2], -JacobiSN[u, 1/2] JacobiDN[u, 1/2]}, {u, 0, 4 EllipticK[1/2]}]`.

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks for that; it is much simpler than what I actually used, but adding the options I used, it gives the exact same output:

`ParametricPlot[{{Sqrt[Cos[t]], Sin[t]/Sqrt[2]}, {-Sqrt[Cos[t]], Sin[t]/Sqrt[2]},
                {Sqrt[Cos[t]], -Sin[t]/Sqrt[2]}, {-Sqrt[Cos[t]], -Sin[t]/Sqrt[2]}}, 
                {t, 0, Pi/2}, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[.75, 0, 0],
                AxesLabel -> {"U", "U'"}, ImageSize -> 400]`

Answer (score 0):

The original equation after modding out constants, etc is the familiar elliptic integral of first kind(for a more detailed introduction see this [note](http://people.fas.harvard.edu/~amathew/232b.pdf). For your application we only need to know if it is periodic, I do not have a definite answer (the addition law for elliptic integrals is not really related). But judged by the [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%20EllipticF%28sin%5E%28-1%29%28y%29,%20-1%29%20from%20-100%20to%20100) of this function it seems highly unlikely it would be periodical. I guess if you are certain the integral is right, working with the information from the wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) might be helpful.

Comment: Are you sure that modding out constants preserves the original nature of the problem? I tell you my point.. $U''+U^3=0$ was the original equation i studied.. then i got, on wolfram alpha, this http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=U%27%27%2BU%5E3%3D0.. and the solution looks periodic to me.. Of course if $U$ is not identically zero..

Comment: well, modding out constants does not change the problem. I think your step from $U''+U^{3}$ to your formula is not justified.

Comment: @uforoboa: In fact, one particular solution of the DE $y^{\prime\prime}+y^3=0$ is the famed *sine lemniscate function* $\mathrm{sl}(u)$, of which much has been written about. In terms of the usual Jacobian elliptic functions: $$\mathrm{sl}(u)=\frac1{\sqrt 2}\mathrm{sd}\left(u\mid\frac12\right)$$ The other solution is the *cosine lemniscate function*, $$\mathrm{cl}(u)=\mathrm{cn}\left(u\mid\frac12\right)$$ Both are, as expected of elliptic functions, doubly periodic.